# How to stop text-transform: capitalize from capitalizing (s)?

Tags: css, google-chrome, capitalization

I have the following:

```html
<h2 style="text-transform: capitalize;">Creating new task(s)</h2>
```

I expect this to display as "Creating New Task(s)". Problem is, in Chrome, it's displaying as "Creating New Task(S)". With a capital (S).

Obviously, it's treating 's' as a word. How do I make that stop?

Comment: I don't think there's any pure CSS was to deal with this. Probably needs JavaScript. Note that this doesn't seem to occur in Firefox but does in Chrome.

Comment: It does not capitalize it in the code snippet. Which browser are you seeing it capitalise in? 

I suppose one way around it would be to encode it with `&#40;` and `&#41;` instead of `(` and `)`.

Comment: So it does, that must be a Chrome bug. I have posted an answer which fixes it for you. Just plonk the `s` into it's own span and make that lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this in Chrome.

Put the `s` in a span and make it `text-transform: lowercase;`:

```html
<h2 style="text-transform: capitalize;">Creating new task(<span style="text-transform: lowercase;">s</span>)</h2>
```